# Missing Web Application directory in JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, jboss7.x, web-deployment

When I deploy my application from Eclipse IDE to `JBoss 7.1.1` application server, I found `myapp.war` directory under `<JBOSS_HOME\standalone\deployments>`directory.

But when I deploy `myppa.war` file of my application from JBoss Admin Console. I did not found under `<JBOSS_HOME\standalone\deployments>`directory.

Where can I get the deployment folder of `war` in `JBoss 7.1.1`?

Comment: Is it possible you deployed the application in domain mode via the console? Look for it in the `<JBOSS_HOME\domain\>` directory ?

Comment: @MukulGoel, I already check, I did not found it.

Answer (score 0):

JBOSS uses vfs when deployment is done using Admin Console:

Try out the following location:

```
  ${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/tmp/vfs
```

Inside this directory you will find mainly two types of directories starting with:

```
 deployment*
 temp*
```

Now inside the directory starting with temp, you will find the contents of the war file. The important point is to pick the latest one.

On browsing the directory you should see a directory starting with **content*** and inside this directory, the contents of webapp.

Comment: thz for your supporting. I don't want to deploy my application in `temp` directory.

Comment: For that you can copy the file to deployments folder, as you were doing manually.